# how to do where clause on a collection in hibernate using @Query?

Tags: hibernate

Say I have an `entity` called `UserSchedule` like following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_schedule")
public class UserSchedule {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Set<Schedule> schedules;
}
```

In my `UserScheduleRepository` I want to filter the schedules. Something like this `@Query("select us from UserSchedule us where us.schedules.id = 1")`. But since schedules is a collection and not `Schedule` entity, this will not be legal. How can I achieve this in hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JPQL Joins ([JPQL Joins Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins))

```
@Query("select us from UserSchedule us, IN(us.schedules) sh where sh.id  = ?1")
UserSchedule getByScheduleId1(long id);

@Query("select us from UserSchedule us join us.schedules sh where sh.id  = ?1")
UserSchedule getByScheduleId2(long id);
```

If you have `@ManyToOne` backreference field like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "schedule")
public class Schedule {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserSchedule schedule;

...
```

You could also try something like

```
@Query("select us from UserSchedule us where us.id in (select s.schedule from Schedule s where s.id = ?1 )")
```

Comment: thanks. i still cant get the join on collection to work but backreference works!